# Reverting back to previous state - drag and drop

Tags: javascript, jquery

After dragging/dropping multiple I'd like the option to cancel so that all of the divs revert back to original state and position when pressed.

*HTML:*

```
<div class="connected">
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 01</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 02</div>
    <div class="myDivs excludeThisCss">Hello 03</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 04</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 05</div>
    <div class="myDivs excludeThisCss">Hello 06</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 07</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 08</div>
    <div class="myDivs excludeThisCss">Hello 09</div>
    <div class="myDivs">Hello 10</div>
</div>
<button id="demo1" onclick="cancel()" title="Button">Cancel</button>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$(function() {
    $(".connected").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connected",
        items: ".myDivs:not(.excludeThisCss)"
    }).disableSelection();
});

function cancel() {
    // alert('cancelled');
}​
```

See the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjsfiddlenetuser/zyUkd/6/

I've seen examples of using the .load function but I do not want to load new data, just refresh the div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another more lightweight solution.

First, on DOM ready let's store the initial indices to `data` of each element.

```
$(".connected").sortable({
    ...
}).children().each(function(index) {
    $(this).data("index", index);
});
```

Then, on cancel, let's restore positions of elements based on the stored indices as follows:

```
function cancel() {
    var indices = [];
    $(".connected").children().each(function() {
        indices.push($(this).data("index"));
    }).each(function(index) {
        var el = $(".connected").children().eq(indices[index]);
        if (!el.is(this)) el.before(this);
    });
}​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zyUkd/13/

Comment: @tpaksu Thanks! Where is my +1? :D Hm, that was the first idea that came to my mind...

Comment: Here it is. :) I was too lazy to code for it, but you succeeded. Congrats.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by putting the elements inside your container inside a variable, then removing/loading the container with the variable data when you press 'cancel'.  It resets it to its original list position if you have it saved in a variable before-hand.

http://jsfiddle.net/zyUkd/12/

Comment: It cancels only the last change.

Answer (score 1):

Here goes the good ol' fashioned way:

Declare a global var to store the element's in the initial order. `var def;`

On your `$(document).ready()`, that's, `$(function(){})`, store the elements in the initial order:

```
def = $('.connected').html();
```

And finally, on your `cancel()` function, restore the elements to the initial order:

```
$('.connected').html(def);
```

[***JSFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/zyUkd/9/)

That's 3 lines of code only and shouldn't take too much memory to store a couple of DOM elements.

You may also backup the `$('.connected')` element to the var, remove the current element from the document and append the original element from the var back to the page's body/container div as well.

Looking through the [API documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-destroy), the `.sortable("destroy")` method should return the sortable items to its initial order, but the destroy method didn't work when I tried it with your example.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend saving the initial container to element's `.data()` collection with key `"initial-container"`, and on revert, `.detach()` and `.append()` to it's `.data("initial-container")`.